# Month difference between two dates - yyyymm format

Tags: php, date

I wanted to calculate the month difference between two yyyymm dates. I have this function below, however it only works if I use yyyy-mm instead.

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2014-01');
$date2 = new DateTime('2013-06');
$mth = mthdiff($date1, $date2);

function mthdiff($date1,$date2){


$diff = $date1->diff($date2);

return (($diff->format('%y') * 12) + $diff->format('%m'));

}
```

Comment: Use `date_parse_from_format` to parse a date in the form you specify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your function to use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
function mthdiff($date1,$date2){
    $d1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ym', $date1);
    $d2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ym', $date2);
    $diff = $d1->diff($d2);
    return (($diff->format('%y') * 12) + $diff->format('%m'));
}
```

Usage:

```
echo mthdiff('201401', '201306');
```

Output:

```
7
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/137758)